# I met some problems about installing yarn with npm/nvm

Tags: node.js, nvm

After i installed nvm, I ran

```
nvm install 8.15.0
```

then I have node@v8.15.0 installed.

But when I ran

```
nvm use 8.15.0
npm install -g yarn
```

I got this message in my terminal:

```
/Users/bellemere/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/yarn -> /Users/bellemere/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
/Users/bellemere/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/bin/yarnpkg -> /Users/bellemere/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js
+ yarn@1.15.2
updated 1 package in 2s
```

Shouldn't yarn be installed under v8.15.0?
Does anyone meet this problem before?

Comment: Please check the version `yarn --version` and see if it installed. That not error but message saying something updated.

Comment: @Seblor I deleted my previous comment.

Comment: @Akshaybarahate, but when I ran yarn, I got "yarn: command not found"

Answer (score 0):

I checked the terminal log and find there was a config file called '~/.npmrc'.

I just deleted the content in it and now everything is OK.